# Two different headlines in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a simple way to have two different post headlines in Wordpress?

I'd like to have a short one on the home page and a more detailed and longer one on the posts page.

Comment: I think so, but *simple* is relative.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a super simple solution, I just want to avoid to install another plugin for it. @h0tw1r3